# When i try to use the variable changed within an if statement it returns NaN

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a neural network but when I try to retrieve the changed state of the variable from the if statement in my js code it just retrieves the state at which I declared the variable instead, is there a fix for this? Also, if anyone knows of a neater way to do those inputs that would be helpful as well.
Edit: I could probably use the switch condition but I'm relatively new to js so I'd need some help or an example of how to implement that into my code.

JS:

```
var input1;
var input2;
var input3;
function myFunction1() {
    if(input1 != 1) {
        input1 = 1;
    }
    else if(input1 != 0) {
        input1 = 0;
    } 
document.getElementById("in1state").innerHTML = input1;
}
function myFunction2() {
    if(input2 != 1) {
        input2 = 1;
    }
    else if(input2 != 0) {
        input2 = 0;
    }

 document.getElementById("in2state").innerHTML = input2;
}
function myFunction3() {
    if(input3 != 1) {
        input3 = 1;
    }
    else if(input3 != 0) {
        input3 = 0;
    }

 document.getElementById("in3state").innerHTML = input3;
}
var neuron1, neuron2, neuron3, neuron4
 var n1Weight, n2Weight, n3Weight, n4Weight
 var n1Bias, n2Bias, n3Bias, n4Bias

n1Weight = 0.6;
n2Weight = 0.2;
n3Weight = 1.0;
n4Weight = 0.6;

n1Bias = 0.4;
n2Bias = 0.8;
n3Bias = 1.0;
n4Bias = 0.6;

neuron1 = (input1 * n1Weight) + (input2 * n1Weight) + (input3 * n1Weight) + n1Bias;
neuron2 = (input1 * n2Weight) + (input2 * n2Weight) + (input3 * n2Weight) + n2Bias;
neuron3 = (input1 * n3Weight) + (input2 * n3Weight) + (input3 * n3Weight) + n3Bias;
neuron4 = (input1 * n4Weight) + (input2 * n4Weight) + (input3 * n4Weight) + n4Bias;
function myRun() {

 document.getElementById("oof").innerHTML = neuron1 + " " + neuron2 + " " + neuron3 + " " + neuron4;
}
```

'''

Comment: Can you be more precise in which line gives the unexpected result, and wat you expect that line to be?

Comment: `NaN` is the result of a numerical operation where one operand cannot be converted to a number. Make sure your inputs are valid number values. As it is, `input1`, `input2` and `input3` are `undefined` (which is not a number value) by default.

Comment: Thank you and yes I know why its returning NaN I just dont know how to fix it, so I declare the variables at the top and there are 3 if/else statements underneath, one for each input variable, they're a part of a function for 3 button inputs in my html code and change the state of said input between 1 and 0. Later in the code I run it through some math and when I use the variable, instead of giving me the result of that if statement, it pulls from the top where I declared them, which wasnt specified as a numerical variable therefore returning NaN, can I use the changed state from the if/else?

Comment: I've tried setting them to zero so it would specify that the variable is a number but it still just pulls from the zero instead of the state that the if statement produces

Answer (score 0):

NAN meaning, not a number.

That's because input1, input2, and input3 are strings. In Javascript, you can't multiply an Integer with String

1 is different than "1"

so to fix this, you would have to parse input1, input2, and input3 by using parseInt

parseInt(input1);

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot I'll make the changes and let you know what happens, but yeah that makes sense, thank you

Comment: So I get the concept but I'm not sure where to put it in my code, I've inserted it a line before the document.getElementById, but it's still returning NaN

Comment: Is this your entire javascript code? I don't see an HTML elements at all.

I'll correct the mistakes I've seen so far.

First mistake: You are incorrectly assigning a variable.
it should be 

input1 = document.getElementById("in1state").innerHTML;

not the other way around.

Second Mistake: you created functions that never get executed. myFunction1(), myFunction2(), and myFunction3() will never get executed because they were never called.

please check this fiddle I got it to produce actual numbers. https://jsfiddle.net/g9an3vmj/

Comment: Hey, yes this is my entire us script so far, but I’m using it with a separate html page, I can’t get the html to post on here because it just executes the code instead of showing what I actually typed, but there are buttons on the html page with an “onclick” event added that executes the functions in my js page, so they’re getting called, and what I’m trying to do is that when you press a button, it toggles that variable between 1 and 0, so I want to tell the inner html on that button to show me the state that the variable is in, not set the variable to what the inner html of the button is.

Comment: I’ll try to edit my post to include the html as well

Comment: *"In Javascript, you can't multiply an Integer with String"* You can actually and the result will be a number. Try `console.log(2 * "5")`.